# How to change free space to unallocated?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I wanted to install Ubuntu 13.10 therefore I have shrunk one of my logical partitions (D:), but the new partition instead of unallocated is free space.

Now if I choose the option to install ubuntu alongside Windows 7 (instead of something else option) does the installer automatically install in that free space or I should convert it to unallocated? Should I have shrunk a primary partition to use that option?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you shrink a volume you get free or unallocated  space. You can't use that space directly until you are not converting that into a partition.

You can convert your unallocated space into partition using `gparted` in live mode before installing Ubuntu or in the middle of installation by selecting "something else".

After converting it into partition you can install OS in it.

If you choose "install ubuntu alongside windows 7" from there on you can choose the size for the partition space for Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,which way do you recommend to install unbuntu,i have partitioned my HD manually and I don't want to take any risk to lose my windows or its data?